# VBA Scripting.Dictionary Filtering issue

Tags: excel, vba

Hey all I'm having an issue with my Scripting Dictionary. it's supposed to filter out given text which it does but it's also filter Numerical values in the column as well (0, 1, 2) which I want those shown.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
'Filter Prefixes
Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
With ActiveSheet
 lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 2 To lr
     Select Case UCase(.Cells(i, "C").Value2)
         Case "NA", "ND", "NH", "NK", "NL", "NQ", "NV"
             'do nothing
         Case Else
             arr.Item(.Cells(i, "C").Value2) = vbNullString
     End Select
 Next i
 .Range("A1:CU" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=arr.keys, 
Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this what you'r looking for:

`arr.Item(CStr(.Cells(i, "C").Value2))`

Comment: This did it! Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Some explanation of how this resolves the "it's also filter Numerical values in the column as well (0, 1, 2) which I want those shown" might be in order. If you replace the one line of code in the question with this one line of code, it is still adding filters to everything that isn't in the select list.

Comment: @Adirmola by adding CStr to the statement adds a data type conversion, so that numerical and text values report as a string.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a test to see if the value is numeric before you add it to your filter dictionary:

```
 Select Case UCase(.Cells(i, "C").Value2)
     Case "NA", "ND", "NH", "NK", "NL", "NQ", "NV"
         'do nothing
     Case Else
         If Not IsNumeric(.Cells(i, "C").Value2) Then
            arr.Item(.Cells(i, "C").Value2) = vbNullString
         End If
 End Select
```

Comment: Well, it will omit numeric values. I believe OP wants to convert numeric values into string.